# Python Membership Initialisation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning

I fail to define an array in my InitializeMembershipWeight function. I am currently working on a C-Means clustering algorithm.

```py
#Membership Initialisation
def initializeMembershipWeights():

  weight = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(k),n)
  weight_array = np.array(weight)
  return weight_array


print(weight_array)
```

```
NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-70f058bffa58> in <module>
----> 1 print(weight_array)

NameError: name 'weight_array' is not defined
```

Comment: You are trying to output the name ( variable ) which is local scoped not global

Comment: It should be `print(initializeMembershipWeights())` but `k` and `n` aren't defined either so you'll still get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to save what the function outputs, then you can print it. Like this

```
def initializeMembershipWeights():

  weight = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(k),n)
  weight_array = np.array(weight)
  return weight_array

weight_array = initializeMembershipWeights()
print(weight_array)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'k' is not defined`

Comment: yeah you need to declare k with a number and n with a  number in the function `k=0.2` `n=10` that will depend on what you want it to be

Comment: ... but you didn't include `k` and `n` as arguments of the `initializeMembershipWeights` function. Or even include them as variables within the function.